# Eigen Matrix Library index operation

Tags: c++, indexing, eigen

Say I have

```
  Eigen::VectorXd r = Eigen::VectorXd::Random(10);
```

now I want the following:

```
  double lb1(-0.1);
  double ub1(0.1);
  double v(5.); 
  for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
      if( (lb1 < r[i]) && (r[i]<ub1))
            r[i] = v;
```

there are many non overlapping (lb1,ub1) and many "v". Is there a easy elegant way to perform this computation without writing two loops (I have a matlab kind of operation in mind)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`.select()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#adfc67de2ba1403e6856bd1b7dd1388f9)

```
r = (r.array() > lb1 && r.array() < ub1).select(v, r);
```

Comment: perfect this is what I was looking for.

Comment: is there a .select() use where I just extract the subarray within lb1 and ub1 ?

Comment: meaning if r = [ 1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]   and i want to get the subset out like (r.array() > 2, && r.array() < 7).something()  gives me the subset [3,4,5,6]

Comment: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html maybe no other way if it is not one block

Comment: no it is not block opration i am talking about. because the elements of r can be random for instance r can be r=[ 3,6,7,1,2,0,1,1,4,9,10]. then block operation wont work. i have to make use of something else.